# My custom wallpaper is gone, and I can't set any existing wallpaper. Large & extra large icons are blank

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons, desktop-customization

Today my Windows 7 Pro booted, but without my custom image desktop image.
The path was correct and image was there (and could be previewed with any software), but Windows didn't display it.
I tried to set it up again, but there was no thumbnails (previews) for it, even for Windows' own wallpapers:

[image: Desktop background]

I tried everything I found on Internet, but with no results.

Besides that, there are two strange side effects I noted:

1. There is no icons in "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers". But if I change from "Large icons" to "Medium icons", they show right!
2. Not all programs (which should be loaded on startup) are present in SysTray. I checked all missing programs and they have checked "Load at startup" (or similar option) as before. I checked ***msconfig*** and there are really missing some items (unchecked).

I checked my computers for viruses (Avira) and malware, but nothing was found.
I haven't installed any software lately.

`Addition 1:`
I have opened registry key *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper* - it was empty. I have changed it to the path of the picture, and it showed a small icon:
[image: Personalization]

`Addition 2:`
This is shown when I try to delete a file:
[image: Delete file dialog]

It seems to me that some sort of Windows image engine has some problem?!

`Addition 3:`
I have found after much digging exactly the same problem at Microsoft site, but without a solution:
[Windows 7 - Folder / File icons dont show up in Large and Extra Large Icon view - Medium Size icon view works ok](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-7-folder-file-icons-dont-show-up-in-large/d0e0e3a6-317b-4c75-b033-b9519e7931dc)

Comment: Check your harddisk for errors, but don't repair them. If they are found, backup first, because then your harddisk is likely dying. Attempting repair may damage it beyond repair.

Comment: I checked my HD without repairing, but there were no errors. It is a 2-years old 256 GB SSD 850 EVO, with 30 GB free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution for my problem!

There are two registry keys which affect this strange behavior:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]
```

and

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]
```

In my Registry they were empty, but they should be like this:

*[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]*
"IconServiceLib"="IconCodecService.dll"
"DdeSendTimeout"=dword:00000000
"DesktopHeapLogging"=dword:00000001
"GDIProcessHandleQuota"=dword:00002710
"ShutdownWarningDialogTimeout"=dword:ffffffff
"USERNestedWindowLimit"=dword:00000032
"USERPostMessageLimit"=dword:00002710
"USERProcessHandleQuota"=dword:00002710
@="mnmsrvc"
"DeviceNotSelectedTimeout"="15"
"Spooler"="yes"
"TransmissionRetryTimeout"="90"

*[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]*
"IconServiceLib"="IconCodecService.dll"
"DdeSendTimeout"=dword:00000000
"DesktopHeapLogging"=dword:00000001
"GDIProcessHandleQuota"=dword:00002710
"ShutdownWarningDialogTimeout"=dword:ffffffff
"USERNestedWindowLimit"=dword:00000032
"USERPostMessageLimit"=dword:00002710
"USERProcessHandleQuota"=dword:00002710
@="mnmsrvc"
"DeviceNotSelectedTimeout"="15"
"Spooler"="yes"
"TransmissionRetryTimeout"="90"

You can make two **.reg** files in Notepad, fill this and enter it in registry. It works immediatelly, there is no need for a system restart!

Of course, you should make a system restore point, just in case.

Source:
[Large & extra large icons blank](https://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/109589-large-extra-large-icons-blank.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had *exactly* the same problem today (and yes, I think this is relevant, so please don't delete this answer, too !) I still wonder why two people had the same weird issue on the same day.

I was now finally able to fix the issue by restoring my system going back to a restore point. My last restore point (2.Oct.18) did not help, but going back to next one (29.Sep.18) brought my system back.

I tried many things before (based on internet tipps) which did not help at all
- resetting or clearing the thumbnail database
- trying updates on Win7
- tried WindowsUpdate.diagcab
- someone suggested to set "username"/AppData to not-hidden
- checked GroupPolicies (were ok)

Comment: I tried the same (except System restore). Now everything is the same, except the my custom wallpaper appeared after today's boot. I restarted several times in Friday, but it not helped?!